# Random char matrix only using pointers

Tags: c

I created a method that random char matrix without using pointers.

Now I need change my code for that random function **so it only uses pointers — no using subscripts `[][]`**.  I need to create 2 char matrices: one big (20X3) and one small (4x4).

I tried to do it...but I didn't use pointers. The 2 matrices should be printed via main.

```
#include <time.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define SIZE 4
#define ROWS 3
#define COLS 20

void matRandomChar(char mat[][COLS], int rows);
void smallMatRandomChar(char smallMat[][SIZE],int size);
void inputMatrix(char **mat,int rows,int cols);

void matRandomChar(char mat[][COLS], int rows)
{
    int i,j;
    for (i=0; i<rows; i++){
        for (j=0; j<COLS; j++)
            mat[i][j] = 'A'+rand()%('Z'-'A'+1);
    }
}

void smallMatRandomChar(char smallMat[][SIZE],int size)
{
    int i,j;
    for (i=0; i<size; i++){
        for (j=0; j<SIZE; j++)
            smallMat[i][j] = 'A'+rand()%('Z'-'A'+1);
    }
}

int main()
{
    char smallMat[SIZE][SIZE];
    char mat[ROWS][COLS];

    srand((unsigned int)time(NULL));
    matRandomChar(mat,ROWS);
    printf("Big matrix:\n");
    printMat(mat,ROWS);

    smallMatRandomChar(smallMat,SIZE);
    printf("Small matrix:\n");
    printSmallMat(smallMat,SIZE);
}
```

I'm using Eclipse on Linux.

Answer (score 0):

Although the simplest change is to change the notation from `matrix[i][j]` to `*(*(matrix + i) + j)`, you can make more streamlined code with many fewer functions by noting that all the elements of an array are contiguous, so you can simply iterating over the elements of an array with a pointer and never adding an offset.

That leads to code like this:

```
#include <time.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define SIZE 4
#define ROWS 3
#define COLS 20

void matRandomChar(char *mat, int rows, int cols);
void printMat(const char *tag, char *base, int rows, int cols);

void matRandomChar(char *mat, int rows, int cols)
{
    char *end = mat + rows * cols;
    while (mat < end)
        *mat++ = 'A' + rand() % ('Z' - 'A' + 1);
}

void printMat(const char *tag, char *base, int rows, int cols)
{
    int i;
    printf("%s (%dx%d):\n", tag, rows, cols);
    for (i = 0; i < rows; i++)
    {
        int j;
        for (j = 0; j < cols; j++)
            printf(" %c", *base++);
        putchar('\n');
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    char smallMat[SIZE][SIZE];
    char mat[ROWS][COLS];

    srand((unsigned int)time(NULL));

    matRandomChar(&mat[0][0], ROWS, COLS);
    printMat("Big matrix", &mat[0][0], ROWS, COLS);

    matRandomChar(&smallMat[0][0], SIZE, SIZE);
    printMat("Small matrix", &smallMat[0][0], SIZE, SIZE);

    return 0;
}
```

In both the auxilliary functions, the code simply steps through the array data one character at a time.

Sample output:

```
Big matrix (3x20):
 P L J T B F Y L W K C P Q X B P K V D V
 K B Q P V X S B K O X C Z S U K T G F I
 E X O X H C W B K W V E F U L S O F Q G
Small matrix (4x4):
 U C R P
 A R F U
 N K Q L
 Y W R M
```

This code will work with compilers that only accept C90 as well as those that accept C99 or later.

I'd probably use variable length array (VLA) notation to avoid duplicating the code, but then it would be sensible to use subscripts rather than pointers.  However, the same general technique can be applied — though using subscripts is far more sensible.  The following code can be compiled with or without `-DNO_PRINTING_SUBSCRIPTS` — the output has the same organization (but the `- A` or `- B` notation tells you which printing code was used).

```
#include <time.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define SIZE 4
#define ROWS 3
#define COLS 20

void matRandomChar(int rows, int cols, char mat[rows][cols]);
void printMat(const char *tag, int rows, int cols, char mat[rows][cols]);

void matRandomChar(int rows, int cols, char mat[rows][cols])
{
    char *ptr = &mat[0][0];
    char *end = &mat[0][0] + rows * cols;
    while (ptr < end)
        *ptr++ = 'A' + rand() % ('Z' - 'A' + 1);
}

#ifdef NO_PRINTING_SUBSCRIPTS

void printMat(const char *tag, int rows, int cols, char mat[rows][cols])
{
    printf("%s (%dx%d) - A:\n", tag, rows, cols);
    char *ptr = &mat[0][0];
    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++)
            printf(" %c", *ptr++);
        putchar('\n');
    }
}

#else

void printMat(const char *tag, int rows, int cols, char mat[rows][cols])
{
    printf("%s (%dx%d) - B:\n", tag, rows, cols);
    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++)
            printf(" %c", mat[i][j]);
        putchar('\n');
    }
}

#endif /* NO_PRINTING_SUBSCRIPTS */

int main(void)
{
    char smallMat[SIZE][SIZE];
    char mat[ROWS][COLS];

    srand((unsigned int)time(NULL));

    matRandomChar(ROWS, COLS, mat);
    printMat("Big matrix", ROWS, COLS, mat);

    matRandomChar(SIZE, SIZE, smallMat);
    printMat("Small matrix", SIZE, SIZE, smallMat);

    return 0;
}
```

Compiled with `-DNO_PRINTING_SUBSCRIPTS`

```
Big matrix (3x20) - A:
 R K Y W Y J U T C O F N Z V H Q X T P W
 Q Z R T B A O A W J O D I K F I C A R E
 V X X C R P C V H E S K G C M T Y B Z D
Small matrix (4x4) - A:
 V R E M
 P T D G
 U C Q F
 D Q B F
```

Compiled with `-UNO_PRINTING_SUBSCRIPTS`

```
Big matrix (3x20) - B:
 L C K V S P C T L V B P G U I O Q L E B
 N S C Y B I L Y G S F Z C H L Z M G A E
 B P A I H E M X H V C M B Z U Y S D W A
Small matrix (4x4) - B:
 O N U T
 H X X P
 P L M L
 K R S F
```

Comment: Waddya mean 'not working for you'?  What version of GCC are you using?  What compiler options are you using?   I use GCC 8.3.0, and compiled with `gcc -O3   -g -std=c11 -Wall -Wextra -Werror -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes -DNO_PRINTING_SUBSCRIPTS mat47.c -o mat47` for example.  If you're compiling in C90 mode, then either (a) upgrade your compiler to GCC 5.x or later so that C11 is the default, or (b) include `-std=c11` (or `-std=gnu11` if you prefer; there are sound reasons to do that on Linux, but not on macOS where I work).

Comment: The first program is using C99 `for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)` notation; if you're adamant that you should be compiling for a standard that is probably older than you are (aka C90), then you need to separate the definition of `i` from the `for` loop: `int i; for (i = 0; i < rows; i++) { int j; for (j = 0; j < cols; j++) … }`.

Comment: I understand (: Thanks for your help... I try run it in other program and it work. @Jonathan Leffler